# Best embeddings transition from 300 to 2 dimension

Tags: embedding, dimension, reduction

I have a question on which I can't find the answer. I want to train 300 dimensional embeddings sentences by taking the average of its components and then presenting them in 2d. But I'm looking for a way to reduce the overlap of the clusters, because I want to see how these sentences are grouped.

History:
I started with reducing the 300-> 2 dimensions using T-SNE, with standard parameters from Sklearn. Then I read that I would better narrow the 300-> 50 with the PCA and then the 50-> 2 T-SNE with PCA init, what really improves the grouping. Do you know of any other methods of reducing, other parameters to improve of these tools, maybe other libraries or even other reduction tools?

- question
  Do you know any better method for receiving embeddings sentences?

Best regards

P.S .
I performed the above steps in python

Comment: This question is more appropriate for stats.stackexchange than stackoverflow.